# How can I justify this existential quantifier transformation in predicate logic?

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm doing the following transformations over a statement with an existential quantifier that I believe is valid, but I don't know how to justify it in my chain of equivalences:

$$
\begin{align}
\exists y \in Y \{ y \in B \land &\exists x \in X \{ x \in A \} \} \\
&\iff \exists x \in X, y \in Y \{ x \in A \land y \in B \} \\
&\iff \exists x \in X \{ x \in A \land \exists y \in Y \{ y \in B \}\}
\end{align}
$$

I couldn't find an existing existential quantifier rule I could name here. Can this be justified, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have access to a rule that when $z$ does not occur free in $P$ then $$(\exists z~Q(z))\wedge P \iff \exists z~(Q(z)\wedge P)$$

Do you have any trouble seeing why that is justified?

This also works in restricted domains, $(\exists z{\in}Z~Q(z))\wedge P\iff \exists z{\in}Z~(P\wedge Q(z))$

So applying this and the commutivity of conjunction, we have $$\begin{align} & \exists y{\in}Y~(y\in B\wedge (\exists x{\in}X~x\in A))
\\ \iff & (\exists y{\in}Y~y\in B)~\wedge~(\exists x{\in}X~x\in A)
\\ \iff & (\exists x{\in}X~ x\in A)~\wedge~(\exists y{\in}Y~y\in B)
\\ \iff & \exists x{\in} X~(x\in A\wedge (\exists y{\in}Y~y\in B))
\\[2ex] \iff & \exists x{\in}X~\exists y{\in} Y~(x\in A\wedge y\in B)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!